# I couldn't install import sass into my project

Tags: npm, sass, dart-sass

when I run the command
**npm install --save-dev sass**
from *bootstrap-v5* folder I'm getting this error shown below

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../sass/sass.js
npm ERR! dest/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck/files/New_Portfolio_project/bootstrap-v5/node_modules/.bin/sass
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../sass/sass.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck/files/New_Portfolio_project/bootstrap-v5/node_modules/.bin/sass'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../sass/sass.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck/files/New_Portfolio_project/bootstrap-v5/node_modules/.bin/sass'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../sass/sass.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.spck/files/New_Portfolio_project/bootstrap-v5/node_modules/.bin/sass'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2021-09-29T17_41_24_947Z-debug.log
```

But I was able to install sass globally with the command **npm i -g sass**.
I'm just trying this out for the first time. And, is there any way to import sass to my project as I have already installed sass globally?

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install node-sass instead of npm install sass